# How to display a label when a checkbox is selected in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a checkbox column in a table, and the checkbox tag holds the id of the table cell.  When a checkbox is selected, I want the name of the user to be displayed next to the checkbox.  The user's name is contained in a label tag that also holds the id of the table cell.

I have this working, but only when the page is refreshed (so that the value of the userid is being pulled from the database).  How do I display the user's name the FIRST time the box is selected?  I suspect this needs to be done in jquery, in the function that is handling the checkbox click.

I have a show/hide for the label tag (for the user's name), and I believe I can put something in this section that puts the value of the user's name into the label?

In the database, the value of the checkbox is ReviewedFlg, and the value of the user's name is ReviewedUser.

```
function reviewchk() {
    var tid = $(this).attr('id');
    var ident = tid.split("-");
    var tabnum = ident[1];
    var ind = tabnum-1;
    var aPos = oTable[ind].fnGetPosition(this);
    var selrow = oTable[ind].fnGetData(aPos[0]);
    var stnum = selrow[0];  //store
    var supnum = selrow[2]; //supplier number
    var invnum = selrow[4]; //invoice number
    var column = aPos[1];
    var usr = ident[3];
    var tdid = ident[2].substring(2);
    var rvalue = 0;

    if($(this).find('input:checked').attr('checked')==='checked') {
        rvalue = 1;
        $('#lblchk-'+tabnum+'-'+tdid).show();
    } else { 
        rvalue = 0; 
        $('#lblchk-'+tabnum+'-'+tdid).hide();
    }    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'edit_errorcode.php',
        async: false,
        data: {
            stnum: stnum,
            supnum: supnum,
            invnum: $(invnum).text(),
            all: 'one',
            value: rvalue,
            column: column,
            user: usr
        }
    });                            

};
```

And HTML/PHP:

```
$reviewcheck = sprintf(
    '<input %s class="chkbx" name="reviewchk%s" id="reviewchk-%s-td%s" type="checkbox"/><label id="lblchk-%s-%s" class="lblchk">&nbsp%s</label>', 
    (trim($r['ReviewedFlg'])==='1' ? 'checked=checked' :''),
    $id,
    $id,
    $tdid,
    $id,
    $tdid,
    (trim($r['ReviewedFlg'])==='1' ? $r['ReviewedUser'] :'')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this in HTML/PHP by adding a style to the label which shows or doesn't show depending on whether the checkbox is initially selected when the page loads.  I also changed the value of the label to be the current user if ReviewedFlg isn't set when the page first loads (as this means the checkbox is not selected).
The jquery did not change, but the HTML/PHP is now:

```
   $showlabel = "display:inline";
   $nolabel = "display:none";

   $reviewcheck = sprintf('<input %s class="chkbx" name="reviewchk%s" id="reviewchk-%s-td%s" type="checkbox"/><label id="lblchk-%s-%s" class="lblchk" style="%s">&nbsp%s</label>',(trim($r['ReviewedFlg'])==='1' ? 'checked=checked' :''),$id,$id,$tdid,$id,$tdid,(trim($r['ReviewedFlg'])==='1' ? $showlabel : $nolabel) ,(trim($r['ReviewedUser'])==='' ? $_SESSION['user'] : $r['ReviewedUser']));
```